# Create button grid dynamically and bind its text values?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I actually have two questions.

I'm working on a Cinema project in WPF (which is connected to an asp.net webservice). On a view I have to show all the reservations of one performance, and for that I need something like a grid on my view, to show all the seats in one room (to show which seat is free / reserved / sold).

At first the grid has only one button (in menu), which is binded to a command (*LoadReservationCommand*) to load all the datas. Until that, the viewmodel doesn't know the sizes of the grid, so that's why it should be created dynamically. Is that possible?

Once I have the grid (buttongrid for example), I should bind its text value to an array of arrays of strings (free, reserved, sold), which comes from the viewmodel. Is there a way to bind it somehow with indexes?

Here is the first part of the constructor of my ViewModel.

Thanks for your help!

```
public ReservationViewModel(IMoziAdminModel model, PerformanceDTO performance)
    {
        _model = model;
        _performance = performance;

        LoadReservationCommand = new DelegateCommand(async (param) =>
        {
            //We need to find in which room the performance will be
            try
            {
                await _model.RoomLoadAsync();
                Rooms = new ObservableCollection<RoomDTO>(_model.Rooms);
            }
            catch
            {
                OnMessageApplication("Error (Loading)");
            }

            foreach (var r in Rooms)
            {
                if (r.Room_Id == _performance.Room_Id)
                {
                    row = r.Rows;
                    column= r.Columns;
                }
            } //And now we know how big the room is, and we could create the buttongrid.

            ......

        });

        .......

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"An array of arrays of strings" ? C'mon ! Be more OO than that !

```
enum SeatState {
    Free,
    // ...
}

class Seat {
    ICommand Buy { get; private set; }
    SeatState State { get; private set; }
    // ...
}

class Room {
    int Rows { get; private set; }
    int Colums { get; private set; }
    IEnumerable<Seat> Seats { get; private set; }
    // ...
}

class ViewModel : BaseClassImplementingINotifyPropertyChange {
    Room CurrentRoom {
        get { ... }
        private set { ... } // Raise event
    }
    ICommand LoadCurrentRoom { get; private set; }
}
```

Then the view

```
<...>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentRoom.Seats}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid
                    Columns="{Binding CurrentRoom.Columns}"
                    Rows="{Binding CurrentRoom.Rows}"
                />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding Buy}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding State}"/>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</...>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add those buttons to a collection on your viewmodel and then bind it to a [ListView](http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1), which will generate buttons based on a template that you specify.

Comment: Your link died, and so did the value of your answer :(